# Google Analytics Server Side Authorization

Tags: google-analytics

I ma working on Google Analytics Embed API to pull some data and I am on Office 365, since I was using Server Side Authorization, I couldn't be able to add the JSON file to the SharePoint. Is there any way I resolve this problem ?

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

The link for more information.

Comment: Is there any other way I can use the JSON file ?